How to add external module in Angular 17 standalone components
I have  Checkbox tree component which has been exported via checkboxtreemoduldle
I want to use this module in another project in same source code.
I am getting browsermodule already loaded issue on runtime.
Project stcuture-
Projects folder
Project 1
Project 2
Shared
Src
App
Checkboxtreemoule
Package.json (common for all)
Here i want to use checkboxtreemdule in project 2.
It is in Angular 17 with standalone
